# Rigidity lemma up to cover

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $X,Y,Z$ be [Edit: normal] proper varieties over $\mathbb{C}$. Let $W\to X\times Y$ be a finite flat surjective morphism, and let $W\to Z$ be a morphism.
Fix $x \in X$ and suppose that $\{x\}\times Y$ is contracted to a point, say $z$, in $Z$ in the following sense:

The fibre over $\{x\}\times Y$ along $W\to X\times Y$ is contracted to $Z$ via $W\to Z$.

If  $W\to X\times Y$ is an isomorphism, then the Rigidity Lemma says that $W\cong X\times Y\to Z$ factors over $X\to Z$. (The map is "independent of $Y$" in some sense.)

Is there some version of the Rigidity Lemma that we can apply in the above situation to see that $W\to Z$ is also "independent of $Y$"? More precisely, I expect that there is a  finite flat morphism $W'\to W$ such that $W'\to Z$ factors over some covering of $X$.

Comment: If the degree of $W$ over $X\times Y$ equals $d$, then there is an induced morphism from $X\times Y$ to the Chow variety parameterizing effective zero-cycles of degree $d$ in $Z$.  Now apply the Rigidity Lemma to the morphism from $X\times Y$ to the Chow variety.

Comment: @Jason Starr. How to you get $0$-cycles in $Z$? (not $W$?)

Comment: @DamianRossler.  Please read an exposition of the Chow variety, such as in the first chapter of “Rational curves on algebraic varieties” by Koll’ar.

Comment: @Jason Starr. The effective zero-cycles of degree $d$ in $Z$ are parameterised by a certain Hilbert scheme, whose definition I am aware of. I would be grateful if you could describe the morphism that you have in mind in a functorial way.

Comment: @DamianRössler  I do not understand your most recent comment.  The Hilbert scheme of $Z$ does not parameterize the effective zero-cycles in $Z$, it parameterizes closed subschemes of $Z$ that have dimension zero.  Please refer to Koll'ar's book for a detailed discussion of the history of the Chow varieties and a description of *a* functor represented by the Chow varieties.  Please note, this functor is not the only choice: in work of Angeniol and David Rydh, there is a more refined functor that is represented by the "Chow scheme" (Koll'ar defines the Chow variety to be a seminormal variety).

Comment: @Jason Starr. Sorry for the muddle. The Hilbert scheme should map to the Chow variety by a dominant morphism. I will have a look - but to be clear, are you saying that the question of the OP has a positive answer? Exactly as suggested by the OP?

Comment: @DamianRössler  "Exactly as suggested by the OP?"  I need to double check the construction by Rydh, but the result is certainly correct after replacing $X$ and $Y$ by their seminormalizations and replacing $W$ by its fiber product over $X\times Y$ with the seminormalization of $X\times Y$.  Koll'ar defines his functor on the category of seminormal schemes.

Comment: @JasonStarr Thank you for this. I am actually only interested in the case that all varieties are normal, and have accordingly edited the question. Would you be like to post your comments as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer but really a long comment. Suppose also that all the varieties in sight are smooth.

Let $p:W\to X$ be the composition of the morphism
$W\to X\times Y$ with the projection on the first factor and let $g:W\to Z$ be the morphism you consider. Let $f:W\to X\times Z$ be the morphism
st $f(w)=(p(w),g(w))$. Let $q:X\times Z\to X$ be the
projection on the first factor. Then we have trivially
$q\circ f=p$ so that $f$ is an $X$-morphism.
If for all $x\in X$, we have $\dim_{\kappa(x)}(W_x,{\cal O}_{W_x})=1$, then you can apply Mumford's Prop. 6.1 in GIT to deduce what your want (by letting $X\to Z$ be $\eta$ composed with the projection on the second factor). In your situation, this last assumption will not be satisfied in general though. However, if the morphism
$W\to X\times Y$ is (finite and) étale then the morphism
$p$ has geometrically reduced fibres, is cohomologically flat in degree $0$ and has a Stein factorisation
$W\stackrel{p'}{\to} X'\to X$, where $p'$ satisfies the above
assumption and $X'\to X$ is 'etale and finite. So if $W\to X\times Y$ is 'etale,
there is a morphism $X'\to Z$ such that $g$ factors through
$p'$.

I am not sure that there is a similar factorisation in general (I believe one could construct a counterexample but I don't have one to hand).

Comment: Thank you very much. This is very helpful.